# LWC - display <lightning-button-group> in one column

Tags: lwc

I am using  in my component but by default, it's displaying a group of buttons in one row. I want to display the grouped buttons in one column. How is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.columnCss {
    display: contents !important;
}
```

```html
<lightning-button-group class="columnCss">
    <lightning-button label="Refresh"></lightning-button><br/>
    <lightning-button label="Edit"></lightning-button><br/>
    <lightning-button label="Save"></lightning-button>
</lightning-button-group>
```